# Angular.js: page flickering on authentication redirect

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I'm implementing some simple client-side authentication logic in Angular.js. The pages involved are:

```
/account#/login    (public)
/account           (require login)
/account#/settings (require login)
```

When a user is not logged in and try to visit either `/account` or `/account/#/settings`, the app is supposed to redirect to the login page.

I have the following routes configured using ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('overview', {
    url: '/',
    restricted: true
  })
  .state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    restricted: true
  })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    restricted: false
  })
```

and upon URL change, I check if the upcoming page is a restricted page and whether the current user is not logged in. If so redirect to login.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, auth) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
    if (next.restricted && !auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('login');
    }
  });
});
```

`auth` is just a service that checks the login status and returns either `true` (logged in) or `false` (not logged in).

**Here's my question:**

Even though this (kind of) works, I see a page flickering issue when trying to visit a restricted page while not logged in. The page flashes the contents of the restricted page quickly before redirecting me to the login page.

I did a little bit researching online and some people have mentioned the potential solution could be using `resolve` when defining my states, since the page won't load unless it resolves successfully. However, when I try to add

```
resolve: {
  load: function(auth) {
    return auth.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

It didn't work. What am I missing? Is using `resolve` the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are currently doing it will check if the user is logged in or not and set `load` to `true` or `false`. Also controller gets instantiated before `load` is resolved which is why you see the flickering. You need to achieve two things here:

1. Make sure that `load` is resolved before the controller is instantiated.
2. If user is not logged in, redirect the user to the login page.

For the first part we need to use a promise as it will be resolved and converted to value before controller is instantiated. This is what the documentation says:

> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and
>   converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the
>   $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

Following code can do that for us:

```
var isLoggedin = ['auth', '$q',
    function(auth, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //assuming auth.isLoggedIn returns a promise
        var loginPromise = auth.isLoggedIn();
        loginPromise.then(
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(error) {
                deferred.reject('Not logged in');
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
];
```

And states will use `isLoggedin`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('overview', {
        url: '/',
        resolve: {
            loggedin: isLoggedin
        }
    })
    .state('settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        resolve: {
            loggedin: isLoggedin
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login'
    })
```

For the second problem, that is redirecting the user to login page, you can listen to `$stateChangeError` event which is fired in case the state is not resolved, and use `$state.go` to redirect the user.

Comment: I found out the cause of flickering was because my overview page was in a static template. Changing the content of that template to just `<div ui-view></div>` solved the issue. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @melonccoli aha that's great to hear from you, Actually, I am facing this same issue. can you please elaborate what actually you have did to solve this?